# Check if string matches another word following a pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, string, match

I got a variable `string` which equals `shid!`

I'd like a regular expression that renders true if the inputed string matches every character of the previous variable `string` in the good order.

As I always fail to explain properly what I want to do, here is an example of possible inputs and outputs:

- `shid!` returns **true**
- `shid` returns **false**
- `shhhhiddd!` returns **true**
- `ssssshhhhiiiiiddd!!!!` returns **true**
- `hsid!` returns **false**

For the ritual question "What did I try", I'm not used to regular expression. So my answer would be this: `"shid!" =~ /s.*!/`, and obviouly this isn't the good answer and I know why, but don't know how to fix it. Thanks for the kind help

Comment: Do you want `'s______h_____________________i_________d___!______'` to match as well?

Comment: Does the string other than `string` (like `"shid!"`) not include the same character more than once?

Comment: @BroiSatse, no sorry.

Comment: @sawa, any inputed string can include the same character more than once, if they are in the good order ;)

Comment: If that is really what you want, then none of the answers given so far gives the correct result.

Comment: @sawa, nope, I answered you in the other comment.. I think that you confused my variable string and the word string itself on my question. That is my fault then. But nobody excepted you didn't understand though

Comment: Sorry, my comment above is wrong. BroiSatse's answer is the only correct one. I don't think I confused the strings. You did. Anyway, it was difficult to mention which is which since you only named `string`, but did not name the other string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
string = 'shid!'
reg = Regexp.new string.split('').join('+')


!!('shid!' =~ reg)    #=> true
!!('shid' =~ reg)     #=> false
!!('shhhhiddd!' =~ reg) #=> true
!!('ssssshhhhiiiiiddd!!!!' =~ reg)  #=> true
!!('hsid!' =~ reg) #=> false
```

Comment: Nice answer with regex, thanks anyways, I'll pick squeeze for my need

Answer (score 3):

You can do using [`#squeeze`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-squeeze)

```
str.squeeze == 'shid!' #=> true
```

Comment: I lost you by one second.

Comment: Note that when a string like `"sshid!"` is given for the right side of `==`, then this answer will (incorrectly) always return `false`, even if `str` includes all characters in the same order, like `"sshhhhiddd!"` (Although, it is much better than Speransky Danil's answer, which even returns `false` when the right side is `"shid!s"` and `str` is `"shid!s"` as well).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've got the question. But maybe it's what you are looking for:

```
str = 'ssssshhhhiiiiiddd!!!!'
str.split('').uniq.join == 'shid!' #=> true
```

Comment: Yes, nice answer, this may be what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Why did someone downvoted that answer? Even if I think `squeeze` is more beautiful, this does the trick very nicely too

Comment: @sidney Your comment above does not make sense given your response comment to my comment on the original question. Why do you expect this to be upvoted, or not to be downvoted?

Comment: @sawa Geez...
I said : "any inputed string can include the same character more than once"
Speransky Danil gave as an input string `ssssshhhhiiiiiddd!!!!`, which indeed includes the same characater more than once (s 5 times, h 4 times and so on, and thus in the good order). What wasn't clear about this on my comment and orginial question? Look closer the exemples :(

Comment: @sidney By "inputed [sic] character", did you mean `"ssssshhhhiiiiiddd!!!!"`? I thought you were mentioning `"shid!"`. It looks like you even misunderstood my comment. Depending on that, even your question does not make sense.

Comment: @sawa, well, I am confuse, I don't understand that last comment of yours anymore. If you escuse the lack of clarity (if it does), Please infer the question based on the correct answer.